# Caliburn.Micro get DataGrid clicked cell's data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I'm using `Caliburn.Micro` and have a `DataGrid`. To fill the `DataGrid`, a `DataTable` is used.

For instance, I have three columns:

COL ID | COL NAME | COL NAME2

If the user clicks on any cell within the `ID` column, I want an event to be triggered and want to get the Cell's containing text (in order to proceed any further).

However, I couldn't find anything on the Internet and am pretty baffled with this.

Comment: Any particular reason to why you did unaccept the answer without any comment...?

Comment: @mm8 I'm guessing way after the fact here, but it's probably because your answer puts the function in the view not the viewmodel like caliburn.micro wants. Although your answer put me on the right track to get to the solution I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event for the DataGridCell and access its Content property. The following code sample should give you the idea.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="dg_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private void dg_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
    TextBlock tb = cell.Content as TextBlock;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, I was trying to do the same thing today and ran across it and ran into the same issue. The answer @mm8 gave didn't quite work because it puts the function in the code behind for the xaml document breaking MVVM that caliburn micro wants.

The following code works with MVVM, (although it feels like there should be an easier method, I haven't found one that targets individual cells rather than rows.)

I have the following defined at the window level in my xaml:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" 
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
```

Then the datagrid becomes:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="yGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="Cell">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedCellsChanged">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="MyGridCellClicked">
                <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding SelectedCells, ElementName=MyGrid}"/>
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Then in the viewmodel:

```
public void MyGridCellClicked(IEnumerable<DataGridCellInfo> cells)
{
    var info = cells.First();
    if(info.Column.Header as string == "id")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((System.Data.DataRow)info.Item)["id"].ToString());
    }
}
```